I am not able to run my flutter project in macos
I have a Mac m1 pro and I have Cocoapods installed it's up to date and I have tried the flutter clean command too but the issue persists. It shows the following error:
--- xcodebuild: WARNING: Using the first of multiple matching destinations:
{ platform:macOS, arch:arm64, id:00006000-001A684C2606801E, name:My Mac }
{ platform:macOS, arch:x86_64, id:00006000-001A684C2606801E, name:My Mac }
/Users/anjanapoudel/Desktop/task/home_page_mobile_app/build/macos/Build/Products/Debug/home_page_mobile_app.app: replacing existing signature
/Users/anjanapoudel/Desktop/task/home_page_mobile_app/build/macos/Build/Products/Debug/home_page_mobile_app.app: 
resource fork, Finder information, or similar detritus not allowedCommand CodeSign failed with a nonzero exit code** BUILD FAILED **

Building macOS application...Error: Build process failed


what we are going to do is to install the cocopods with arch arm compatible version
in your project terminal
flutter pub get

then navigate to iOS folder using
cd ios

then
sudo arch -x86_64 gem install ffi

and last thing
arch -x86_64 pod install

Alternatively you could remove pod file then
pod init

the last option you may delete the whole IOS folder then
the below command will recreate the IOS folder again
flutter create --platforms=iOS .

